# Subtract ordered lists

Tags: beginner, ocaml

Newbie OCaml review:

Given lists `xs` and `ys` that are both ordered in the same way (e.g. monotonically ordered integers), I want to return a list containing all elements of `xs` not in `ys`, with order preserved.  I can assume that the elements in `ys` are a (perhaps improper) subset of `xs`.

The key is that I have to walk two lists, but they are different lengths and I don't necessarily move through them at the same rate, so I can't use one of the `fold2` functions, as far as I can see.

```
let rec subtract_list xs ys =
  match xs with 
  | [] -> []
  | x::more_xs -> match ys with
                  | [] -> xs
                  | y::more_ys -> 
                      if x = y 
                      then subtract_list more_xs more_ys
                      else x::(subtract_list more_xs ys)
```

This is the best method I came up with, but I wonder if there's some better strategy that doesn't involve embedding a `match` inside a `match` or that's simpler or more idiomatic in some other way.  This version isn't tail recursive, but that's OK.  Comments on indentation or other formatting issues are welcome too.

Comment: this is a common problem i've run into using .net applications. i'd recommend googling 'subtract one list from another .net c#' and to then copy some of the implementations for your own purposes?

Comment: Thanks @BKSpurgeon.  I assume you meant F#.   That's a good idea--to search for F# solutions--and maybe Haskell or even SML solutions--when looking for OCaml solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can merge all the testing into one `match` expression:

```
let rec subtract_list xs ys =
  match xs, ys with 
  | [], _ -> []
  | _, [] -> xs
  | x :: xs', y :: ys' when x = y ->
      subtract_list xs' ys'
  | x :: xs', _ ->
      x :: (subtract_list xs' ys)
```

This also gets rid of the `if` expression.

Comment: One can understand your version more quickly.  Is that a common idiom--using the tick/quote/prime that way?

Comment: Yes. It looks more "math-y". :) OCaml supports multiple ticks, so you could have `x''`. But then it starts to get confusing.

Comment: Right--OK.  Makes sense.

Comment: You can also shadow names. E.g. in `x :: xs', _ -> x :: (subtract_list xs' ys)` the original binding of `xs` is never used, so we could safely shadow it: `x :: xs, _ -> x :: (subtract_list xs ys)`